# Cumulative add until threshold if reached move to next row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a requirement where I have 2 tables

| mid | mrid | mpid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 63 | 12134 |
| 1 | 64 | 12135 |
| 1 | 65 | 12136 |
| 2 | 63 | 12237 |
| 2 | 64 | 12238 |
| 2 | 65 | 12239 |

and another table

| mid | aid | ctid | ctv |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 | 5813 | 10000 |
| 1 | 12 | 5817 | 6 |
| 1 | 13 | 5813 | 1000 |
| 1 | 13 | 5817 | 4 |
| 1 | 14 | 5813 | 2000 |
| 1 | 14 | 5817 | 6 |
| 2 | 15 | 5813 | 15000 |
| 2 | 15 | 5817 | 10 |
| 2 | 16 | 5813 | 4000 |
| 2 | 16 | 5817 | 3 |
| 2 | 17 | 5813 | 8000 |
| 2 | 17 | 5817 | 9 |

Here in table 2 ctid has 2 value 5813 is points and 5817 is nights. And table 2 has value where column mrid 63 is silver (person got 10000 points or 10 nights)
64 is gold (person got 20000 points or 20 nights)
65 is Platinum (person got 40000 points or 30 nights)

If I have to bring the data like the below format:

| mid | mrid | mpid | ctv |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 63 | 12134 | 10000 |
| 1 | 64 | 12135 | 10000+1000+2000 |
| 1 | 65 | 12136 | 10000+1000+2000 |
| 1 | 63 | 12134 | 6 |
| 1 | 64 | 12135 | 6+4+6 |
| 1 | 65 | 12136 | 6+4+6 |
| 2 | 63 | 12237 | 15000 |
| 2 | 64 | 12238 | 15000+4000+8000 |
| 2 | 65 | 12239 | 15000+4000+8000 |
| 2 | 63 | 12237 | 10 |
| 2 | 64 | 12238 | 10+3+9 |
| 2 | 65 | 12239 | 10+3+9 |

What are the options I can follow in SQL Server to achieve that. Here if you see the ctv column its been based on the mrid column definition provided above where if it reached silver the values will not added on that row and added to next row unit next row reach to the gold.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: You are looking for window/analytic functions.

Comment: This kind of process is not really easy to do in SQL -- it would make more sense to do this in the client process instead.

Comment: @DaleK Thanks for you suggestion.Its quite complex to put the table so I used image.
About the function idea i used it it does not seems that easy as using analytical function.

Comment: Yeah, but images are not user friendly and not welcome on this site... hence why the guide asked you not to use them. In what you have shown above will be smaller, neater and easier to read as tabular text than as an image. An if you have attempted an analytic function approach, please show us what you tried.

Comment: If you want people to experiement with queries to provide you with answers that's more likely to happen when you provide sample data in a consumable format - DDL and DML to populate it. Not as many people would be interested enough to transcribe the data from your images before they even start experimenting.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution, but it was out of sheer determination. I cannot say that I completely understand your problem, but knowing the output you desire I have a working query. I cannot order the results as you show, but it matches your results.

I created some table variables to store the data presented and used some common table expressions to craft the result. I am not proud of this, but it works!

```sql
DECLARE @t1 TABLE ([mid] INT NOT NULL, [mrid] INT NOT NULL, [mpid] INT NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO @t1([mid],[mrid],[mpid])
VALUES (1,63,12134),(1,64,12135),(1,65,12136),(2,63,12237),(2,64,12238),(2,65,12239);

DECLARE @t2 TABLE ([mid] INT NOT NULL, [aid] INT NOT NULL, 
[ctid] INT NOT NULL, [ctv] INT NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO @t2([mid],[aid],[ctid],[ctv])
VALUES (1,12,5813,10000),(1,12,5817,6),(1,13,5813,1000),(1,13,5817,4),(1,14,5813,2000),
(1,14,5817,6),(2,15,5813,15000),(2,15,5817,10),(2,16,5813,4000),(2,16,5817,3),(2,17,5813,8000),
(2,17,5817,9);

/*
t2.ctid = 5813 => points
t2.ctid = 5817 => nights

t1.mrid = 63 => silver (10,000 points or 10 nights)
t1.mrid = 64 => gold (20,000 points or 20 nights)
t1.mrid = 63 => platinum (40,000 points or 40 nights)
*/

WITH part1 AS (
SELECT [t1].[mid], [t1].[mrid], [t1].[mpid], [t2].[ctid], [t2].[ctv], 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [t1].[mid] ORDER BY [t1].[mpid]) AS [rn]
FROM @t1 AS t1 
INNER JOIN @t2 AS t2 ON [t2].[mid] = [t1].[mid] 
WHERE t2.[ctid] = 5813
), part2 AS (
SELECT [part1].[mid], [part1].[mrid], [part1].[mpid], SUM([part1].[ctv]) AS [ctv], 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [part1].[mid] ORDER BY [part1].[mpid]) AS [rn]
FROM [part1] 
GROUP BY [part1].[mid], [part1].[mrid], [part1].[mpid]
), part3 AS (
SELECT [t1].[mid], [t1].[mrid], [t1].[mpid], [t2].[ctid], [t2].[ctv], 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [t1].[mid] ORDER BY [t1].[mpid]) AS rn
FROM @t1 AS t1 
INNER JOIN @t2 AS t2 ON [t2].[mid] = [t1].[mid] 
WHERE t2.[ctid] = 5817
), part4 AS (
SELECT [part3].[mid], [part3].[mrid], [part3].[mpid], SUM([part3].[ctv]) AS [ctv], 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [part3].[mid] ORDER BY [part3].[mpid]) AS [rn]
FROM [part3] 
GROUP BY [part3].[mid], [part3].[mrid], [part3].[mpid]) 
SELECT [part1].[mid], [part1].[mrid], [part1].[mpid], [part1].[ctv] FROM [part1] WHERE [part1].[rn] = 1 
UNION ALL 
SELECT [part2].[mid], [part2].[mrid], [part2].[mpid], [part2].[ctv] FROM [part2] WHERE [part2].[rn] <> 1
UNION ALL 
SELECT [part3].[mid], [part3].[mrid], [part3].[mpid], [part3].[ctv] FROM [part3] WHERE [part3].[rn] = 1
UNION ALL 
SELECT [part4].[mid], [part4].[mrid], [part4].[mpid], [part4].[ctv] FROM [part4] WHERE [part4].[rn] <> 1
ORDER BY [part1].[mid], [part1].[mrid], [part1].[mpid];
```

The output is:

| mid | mrid | mpid | ctv |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 63 | 12134 | 10000 |
| 1 | 63 | 12134 | 6 |
| 1 | 64 | 12135 | 13000 |
| 1 | 64 | 12135 | 16 |
| 1 | 65 | 12136 | 16 |
| 1 | 65 | 12136 | 13000 |
| 2 | 63 | 12237 | 10 |
| 2 | 63 | 12237 | 15000 |
| 2 | 64 | 12238 | 27000 |
| 2 | 64 | 12238 | 22 |
| 2 | 65 | 12239 | 22 |
| 2 | 65 | 12239 | 27000 |

Sorry I cannot explain it better detail, but you should be able to see how I built it up piecemeal.